# Does these ifs statments decrease performance?

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture

So, I'm modularizing my app with architecture, now, in my view I'm getting **fullName**, **password 1 (pw1)** , **password2 (pw2)** and **email**.

I have a button action that call `signUp()` method

### signup

```
override fun signUp() {
        val fullName:String = etxt_name.text.trim().toString()
        val email:String = etxt_email.text.trim().toString()
        val pw1:String = etxt_pw1.text.trim().toString()
        val pw2:String = etxt_pw2.text.trim().toString()

        if(presenter.isEmailValid(email)){

            if(presenter.passwordsMatch(pw1,pw2)){

                if(presenter.isPasswordEmpty(pw1,pw2)){

                    etxt_pw1.setError("Empty field")
                    etxt_pw2.setError("Empty field")
                    return

                }else{
                    if(presenter.isNameEmpty(fullName)){

                        etxt_name.setError("Empty name")
                        return

                    }else{
                        presenter.signUp(fullName,email,pw1)
                    }

                }

            }else{
                etxt_pw1.setError("Passwords does not match")
                etxt_pw2.setError("Passwords does not match")
                return
            }

        }else{

            etxt_email.setError("Invalid E-mail")
            return
        }

    }
```

This calls the methods in my **Presenter** to validate each field

### Presenter

```
   override fun passwordsMatch(pw1: String, pw2: String): Boolean {
        return pw1.equals(pw2)
    }

    override fun isEmailValid(email: String): Boolean {
        return Pattern.matches(
            "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])",
            email)
    }

    override fun isPasswordEmpty(pw1: String, pw2: String): Boolean {
        return !(pw1.isEmpty() || pw2.isEmpty())
    }

    override fun isNameEmpty(fullName: String): Boolean {
        return fullName.isEmpty()
    }
```

### My question

I's this way I'm implementing it the correct approach ? or should I make it better ? If so, any tips will be apreciated, also, are those if statments decreasing performance in the signup method ?

Thanks

Comment: Side note : Android has a built in email validator `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good, but could be modified to be more easily understood by others. For example, the funtion `signUp()` could be recreated like this:

```
override fun signUp() {
    val fullName:String = etxt_name.text.trim().toString()
    val email:String = etxt_email.text.trim().toString()
    val pw1:String = etxt_pw1.text.trim().toString()
    val pw2:String = etxt_pw2.text.trim().toString()

    if (!presenter.isEmailValid(email)) {
        etxt_email.setError("Invalid E-mail")
        return
    }

    if (!presenter.passwordsMatch(pw1,pw2)) {
        etxt_pw1.setError("Passwords does not match")
        etxt_pw2.setError("Passwords does not match")
        return
    }

    if (presenter.isPasswordEmpty(pw1,pw2)) {
        etxt_pw1.setError("Empty field")
        etxt_pw2.setError("Empty field")
        return
    }

    if (presenter.isNameEmpty(fullName)) {
        etxt_name.setError("Empty name")
        return
    }

    presenter.signUp(fullName, email, pw1)
}
```

The if statments are not decreasing performance, as far as I know, this is a common way to create validators. As for your other file it seems right. I hope this could help you :)

Comment: Thanks Benoit ! I was about to use https://github.com/thyrlian/AwesomeValidation , but I didnt want to since I dont want to have mutliple libraries in the project for just validate fields

Comment: No problem! If you want more inspiration on how to create your own validators, Android Studio has one. Create a new project in Android Studio, and select the Login Activity, you will see how they do validation. It is a little more complex, but it's the same concept